# Passing data to next screen in react-router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, web-applications, react-router

I want to pass the username variable to the next screen in react-router v6:

```
// Sample 
const App = () => {

const pass = () => {
//Variable to be passed
let username = 'john.smith'
  navigate('next-screen', /*data*/)
}

return(
  <button onClick = {pass}></button>
)
}


export default App
```

Comment: First, put it in the localStorage and get the value in your next screen. Doing so will persist your value across page refreshes.

Comment: Have you read the [react-router-v6 blog](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/)? It outlines the syntax. Just add the state object: `navigate('next-screen', { username });`.

Comment: @DrewReese How can I access the variable in the next screen?

Comment: Same as before I believe, route props: `props.location.state.username`.

Answer (score 0):

`navigate('next-screen', {userName});`

React-router provides few useful property, just make sure the component renders against `next-screen` is exported with `withRouter(component)`, if you followed these steps then in your `next-screen` console `this.props.location.state.userName` and you'll have your variable to next component.

**NOTE:** If your navigate is same as `this.props.history.push`

If not then add withRouter to your current component too which will give you access to `history` in the current component as a prop.

Comment: OP is using react-router-dom v6, `navigation` replaces `history` for route pushes. V6 [Getting Started](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/installation/getting-started.md) and [v5 to v6 Migration Guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md).

Comment: Nonetheless you can still get `state` from `location.state.userName`

Comment: If you are using hooks then simply use `useLocation` and access `location.state.userName`.